# Find $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+x)}{x-\pi}$ without using L'Hôpital.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I tried:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+x)}{x-\pi} = -\frac{\sin(x)}{x-\pi} = ???$$

What do I do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to \pi}  -\frac{\sin x}{x-\pi} =\lim_{x\to \pi}  -\frac{\sin (\pi-x)}{x-\pi} = \lim_{x\to \pi}  \frac{\sin (\pi-x)}{\pi-x}$$
Define $t=\pi -x$ then $x\to \pi \Rightarrow t\to 0$ and we get
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin t}{t} = 1$$

Comment: Why is $\lim_{x\to \pi}  -\frac{\sin x}{x-\pi} =\lim_{x\to \pi}  -\frac{\sin (\pi-x)}{x-\pi} $?

Comment: Because $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$

Comment: Right, I had forgotten about that one. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the *definition* of the derivative at $x=\pi$ of the function $g(x)=\cos(\frac{\pi}2+x)$. (Note that $g(\pi)=0$.) No need for L'Hôpital. If you don't know the chain rule, use a trig identity to write $g(x)=-\sin x$. (Oh, I guess you already did this.) Then it's the derivative of $-\sin(x)$ at $x=\pi$.

(And if you aren't supposed to use calculus at all, then ... convert this to the $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{\sin t}t$ limit.)